# How to exclude a path from the context path of a deployment?

Tags: jetty

I use Jetty 11. I have two context files in `/opt/web/mybase/webapps`, one for Certbot (Let's Encrypt) and another one for the web app context at the root. [The first context file](https://sourceforge.net/p/red-feed-aggregator/code/ci/master/tree/minimal_self_hosting_setup.sh#l391) must not redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in order to let Certbot work when the SSL certificate has just been revoked, its context path is `/.well-known/acme-challenge`. The second context file must redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (by forcing the transport type "confidential" in web.xml), the context path is `/`, it's similar to [this context file](https://sourceforge.net/p/red-feed-aggregator/code/ci/master/tree/red-feed-aggregator.xml). Certbot writes something in `/.well-known/acme-challenge` and expects to see it at http://example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge.

How can I indicate in the second context file that everything except the stuff in `/.well-known/acme-challenge` must be handled by the servlet of the WAR in this context file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your trust into the servlet spec request path mapping rules, and things will get really easy.

For context paths, the longest match is used.
So for contexts `/foo` and `/`, and a request of `/foo/example.txt`, the longest match is context `/foo`

Lets take a look at this example `${jetty.base}`

```
certbot-example/
├── etc/
│   └── keystore.p12
├── start.d/
│   ├── deploy.ini
│   ├── http.ini
│   ├── https.ini
│   ├── server.ini
│   └── ssl.ini
└── webapps/
    ├── ROOT/
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── WEB-INF/
    │       └── web.xml
    ├── well-known/
    │   └── certbot.txt
    └── well-known.xml
```

It has the following configuration ...

```
$ java -jar ${JETTY_HOME}/start.jar --list-config
Enabled Modules:
----------------
    0) resources       transitive provider of resources for logging-jetty
    1) logging/slf4j   transitive provider of logging/slf4j for logging-jetty
                       dynamic dependency of logging-jetty
    2) logging-jetty   transitive provider of logging for threadpool
                       transitive provider of logging for bytebufferpool
                       transitive provider of logging for server
    3) bytebufferpool  transitive provider of bytebufferpool for server
                       init template available with --add-module=bytebufferpool
    4) threadpool      transitive provider of threadpool for server
                       init template available with --add-module=threadpool
    5) server          ${jetty.base}/start.d/server.ini
    6) security        transitive provider of security for webapp
    7) servlet         transitive provider of servlet for webapp
    8) webapp          transitive provider of webapp for deploy
                       init template available with --add-module=webapp
    9) deploy          ${jetty.base}/start.d/deploy.ini
   10) http            ${jetty.base}/start.d/http.ini
   11) ssl             ${jetty.base}/start.d/ssl.ini
   12) https           ${jetty.base}/start.d/https.ini

...(snip)... 

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 10.0.6
 jetty.tag.version = jetty-10.0.6
 jetty.build = 37e7731b4b142a882d73974ff3bec78d621bd674
 jetty.home = /home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-10.0.6
 jetty.base = /home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example

...(snip)... 

Properties:
-----------
  ...(snip)... 
 jetty.httpConfig.securePort = 8443
```

With the following content in `${jetty.base}/webapps/` ...

```
[certbot-example]$ cat webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml 
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
  <display-name>Example WebApp</display-name>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>

[certbot-example]$ cat webapps/ROOT/index.html 
<html><body><h2>Hello World!</h2></body></html>

[certbot-example]$ cat webapps/well-known/certbot.txt 
example-cert-bot

[certbot-example]$ cat webapps/well-known.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/.well-known</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="." />/well-known</Set>
</Configure>
```

Once we start jetty, we can see that 2 webapps contexts are deployed ...

```
[certbot-example]$ java -jar ../../jetty-home-10.0.6/start.jar
2021-08-06 08:29:27.121:INFO :oejs.Server:main: jetty-10.0.6; built: 2021-06-29T15:28:56.259Z; git: 37e7731b4b142a882d73974ff3bec78d621bd674; jvm 11.0.12+7
2021-08-06 08:29:27.151:INFO :oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/webapps/]
2021-08-06 08:29:27.227:INFO :oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /.well-known, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2021-08-06 08:29:27.234:INFO :oejss.DefaultSessionIdManager:main: Session workerName=node0
2021-08-06 08:29:27.253:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@30bce90b{/.well-known,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/webapps/well-known/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/webapps/well-known}
2021-08-06 08:29:27.264:INFO :oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2021-08-06 08:29:27.269:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@10cf09e8{Example WebApp,/,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/webapps/ROOT/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/webapps/ROOT}
2021-08-06 08:29:27.432:INFO :oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@57abad67(mykey,h=[localhost],a=[],w=[]) for Server@584f54e6[provider=null,keyStore=file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/certbot-example/etc/keystore.p12,trustStore=null]
2021-08-06 08:29:27.515:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1af687fe{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-08-06 08:29:27.522:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@70efb718{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2021-08-06 08:29:27.534:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started Server@1e16c0aa{STARTING}[10.0.6,sto=5000] @1071ms
```

The two entries of note ...

- Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@30bce90b{`/.well-known`, `file:///.../certbot-example/webapps/well-known/`, AVAILABLE}
- Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@10cf09e8{Example WebApp, `/`, `file:///.../certbot-example/webapps/ROOT/`, AVAILABLE}

This means that we have 2 contexts defined,
one for serving requests to path `http://<machine>/.well-known/`
and another for `http://<machine>/`

If we make a few requests you'll see the behavior ...

Make a request to the context `/.well-known` (notice that http and https works)

```sh
$ curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/.well-known/certbot.txt
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /.well-known/certbot.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:11:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 17
< Server: Jetty(10.0.6)
< 
example-cert-bot

$ curl -k -vvv https://localhost:8443/.well-known/certbot.txt
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
...(snip)...
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /.well-known/certbot.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:11:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 17
< Server: Jetty(10.0.6)
< 
example-cert-bot
```

But if we request something from the context `/` we can only do so with https.

```sh
$ curl -k -L -vvv http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Location: https://localhost:8443/
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(10.0.6)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://localhost:8443/'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
..(snip)...
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:08:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 48
< Server: Jetty(10.0.6)
< 
<html><body><h2>Hello World!</h2></body></html>
* Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it's easier than I imagined. I saw your suggestion consisting in using the transport guarantee "confidential" to implement HTTPS only in another post on StackOverflow, I kept it in my mind, it's going to be very useful.